# How to use JSDoc to document `const z = (y) => (a, b = 3) => []`

Tags: vue.js, vuex, jsdoc

I need to figure out a way to document the below function with JSDoc.

```js
/**
 * Return the collection from cache based on the hash, page and pagination count
 * @param state
 * @returns {function({hash: *, page: *, pagination?: *}): ([]|*)}
 */

export const collection = (state) => ({ hash, page, pagination = 60 }) => {
  if (!state.models[hash]) return []
  // deep copy the object because of the collection property array
  const model = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.models[hash]))
  const end = page * pagination
  const start = end - pagination
  return model.collection.splice(start, end)
}
```

### *Edit*

I have fixed the error I was receiving by changing the comment above to

```js
/**
 * Return the collection from cache based on the hash, page and pagination count
 * @type {object}
 * @param state
 * @returns {function({hash: *, page: *, pagination: *}): Array}
 */
```

<s>I receive this error:</s>

```
ERROR: Unable to parse a tag's type expression for source file 
/app/src/store/cache/getters.js in line 9 with tag title "returns" 
and text "{function({hash: *, page: *, pagination?: *}): ([]|*)}":
Invalid type expression "function({hash: *, page: *, pagination?: *}):
([]|*)": Expected "#", "$", "(", ",", "-", ".", "/", "0", ":", "<",
"=", "@", "[]", "\\", "_", "}", "~", "‌", "‍", Unicode combining mark,
Unicode decimal number, Unicode letter number, Unicode lowercase letter,
Unicode modifier letter, Unicode other letter, Unicode punctuation
connector, Unicode titlecase letter, Unicode uppercase letter, or
[1-9] but "?" found.
```

#### package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.5",
    "jsdoc-vuejs": "^3.0.9",
    "jsdoc-vuex-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    ...
  },
```

https://github.com/Kocal/jsdoc-vuejs
https://github.com/martiensk/vuex-jsdoc